# Laptop doesn't suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo

My laptop is Lenova T530 and I use Ubuntu 13.10. When I try to suspend the laptop (either by selecting `suspend` from the menu or by closing the lid), it doesn't suspend. It appears that it's trying to suspend but in a moment it awakes.

Any suggestion to get this fixed is highly appreaciated

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with a ThinkPad X1 Carbon...
The problem began few weeks ago, usually after a day of work.

I'm trying the solution from [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290&p=12014988#post12014988) and so far it looks like it's working!

Below are the details:

1. Open up a terminal and create a script file as follows:

   Code:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
   ```
2. If and only if you have problems with your current script and your machine refuses to sleep or wake up on kernel 3.2.0-24-generic then replace the entire code with the following:

   Code:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # File: "/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd".
   TMPLIST=/tmp/ehci-dev-list

   case "${1}" in
           hibernate|suspend)

           ;;
           resume|thaw)
            chvt 1
            chvt 7
           ;;
   esac
   ```
3. Give the script permission to run by typing the following in the terminal:

   Code:

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
   ```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @muditkapil: See comment above.  More important then an edit (which I approved BTW)

Comment: @Fabby kindly see if this is correct edit

Comment: @MuditKapil Good one!  But the OP should have done this work himself...  (I was trying to tell you, being my confused and confusing self,  to flag the answer....)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Anyhow This answer would help future Users so good for community