# Suspend doesn't work after update to latest version - Ubuntu 20.10 - Lenovo T440p

Tags: suspend, 20.10

I updated Ubuntu via apt-update-apt-upgrade and since then suspend doesn't work any more. It tries to suspend and the suspend routine is listed in htop, but it wakes back up again right after.

The solution described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511105/laptop-doesnt-suspend) doesn't work.

From other posts, I have to assume, that this is an kernel bug. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Please include the output of `dmesg | tail -50` right after the computer fails to suspend.

Comment: try to suspend by systemctl:
```
systemctl suspend
```

Comment: @SiamakAmo  After the laptop went to suspend by inactivity timeout once,, the problem is not reproducable any more. Suspend works now, like it should. I keep this open nevertheless, in case it reoccurs. Then I will try the things you requested here.

Comment: @metarmask See comment above.